# Storing data for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

What is the best way to store data for the iPhone? I will be developing an iPhone app in Objective-C which will take data from end users. This data will need to be save and loaded at various points.

Essentially, what is the best combination of languages and frameworks to use in order to develop the above (i.e. should I be aware of any compatibility or like issues regarding the objective-c language)?

EDIT: Are there any particular reasons why to choose sqllite over core data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey, the best way to store and manage data is Core Data framework, you can read about it in official docs.

Answer (score 2):

Two of the most popular and reasonable solutions:

1. Apple's native solution: CoreData
2. sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

I used sqlite3 for my applications. If you use mySQL then you'll be very comfortable to use sqlite3. However, people recommend CoreData due to its ease of use and iOS support.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add my vote for the CoreData solution. I investigated all the options (CoreData, sqlite3 and plists) and CoreData seemed to be the right option for me.

I found a brilliant tutorial on it for iOS 5 [here](http://timroadley.com/2012/02/09/core-data-basics-part-1-storyboards-delegation/)